# VB.NET XmlTextReader bytes read

Tags: xml, vb.net

I need to parse a large (> 3GB) XML file and am using XmlTextReader to loop through the elements like so:

```
oReader = New XmlTextReader(filename)
oReader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.Significant

While oReader.Read()
    ' Processing in here
End While
```

Since this is expected to take a long time, I'd like to provide a progress indicator of how much of the XML file has been processed so far. My plan was to get the total file size of the XML file before processing and then keep a running sum of how many bytes the XmlTextReader has processed so that I can calculate the percentage complete. But, I can't figure out how to get the number of bytes the underlying stream of XmlTextReader has buffered. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Filestream as input for the XMLTextReader, so you can get the current position from that stream.

```
Using _xmlfile As New IO.FileStream("x:\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.xml", IO.FileMode.Open)
    Using oReader As New XmlTextReader(_xmlfile)
        oReader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.Significant
            While oReader.Read()
                ' Current filepos via: _xmlfile.Position
                ' Processing in here
            End While
    End Using
End Using
```